# Get total from json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have json of students

```
"students":{
    "ABC":{
        "eng": 25,
        "maths": 50,
        "sci": 25
    },
    "DEF": {
        "eng": 25,
        "maths": 48,
        "sci": 30
    }
}
```

I want to get the total marks per student.

Here is what I followed:

```
var marksCount = [];
$.each(response['students'], function(name, marksVal) {

    $.each(marksVal, function(index, val) {
        if (marksCount[name] == 'undefined') {
            marksCount[name] = 0;
            marksCount[name].push(val);
        }
    });
});

var studName = '', studMarks = 0;
$.each(marksCount, function(i, v)){
    studName = i;
    studMarks += i;
}


student name  total
ABC             100
DEF             103
```

Help I'm stuck.

Comment: Hey there, it looks like your question could use a bit of editing so that the code displays correctly. It would also be helpful if you included a bit about what is going wrong as well as what part you are stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jQuery to achieve this.

```js
// a function to sum up an array of numbers
function sumValues(values) {
    return values.reduce(function (sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    });
}

var students = {
    ABC: {
        eng: 25,
        maths: 50,
        sci: 25
    },
    DEF: {
        eng: 25,
        maths: 48,
        sci: 30
    }
};

// loop through all students in the list
Object.keys(students).forEach(function (studentName) {
    // get student details by name
    var student = students[studentName];

    // get all the grades for the student
    var grades = Object.values(student);

    // sum them up
    var total = sumValues(grades);

    console.log("Total for " + studentName + " is " + total);
});
```

You can achieve a lot without jQuery, and whenever you use it you should evaluate whether you're using it correctly. It's incredibly simple to sum up values with JavaScript alone, so you should do that.

Take a look at [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for more examples of how to write the code you want without using jQuery.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain why you have downvoted this answer so I can improve it? It is fully explained and provides a concise answer to the question. If you think that the answer doesn't meet the StackOverflow standards, I'd appreciate it if you could point out my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var students = {
ABC:{
    eng: 25,
    maths: 50,
    sci: 25
},
DEF: {
    eng: 25,
    maths: 48,
    sci: 30
}};
$.each(students, function(value, course) {
    console.log("Student: " + value);

    var sum = 0;
    $.each(course, function(grade, mark){
       sum += mark;
    })

    console.log("Sum: "+ sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First you need to convert Json to Javascript object, after that you can apply below code:

```
var students = {
ABC:{
    eng: 25,
    maths: 50,
    sci: 25
},
DEF: {
    eng: 25,
    maths: 48,
    sci: 30
}};
$.each(students, function(value, course) {
    console.log("Student: " + value);

    var sum = 0;
    $.each(course, function(grade, mark){
       sum += mark;
    })

    console.log("Sum: "+ sum);
});
```

Comment: But i need the summation of marks for that particular student @jaffal

Comment: @jaydhawan yes it will print to console:
 Student: ABC
 Sum: 100
 Student: DEF
 Sum: 103

Comment: @Jaffal Why do you believe that JQuery is the best solution for this?

Comment: @JamesMonger I don't believe it's the best solution but since the question is already about using jQuery to solve the problem I just rewrote it in a proper way.

Comment: I think it may be best to explain why @jaydhawan maybe doesn't need to use JQuery here, and explain what he can use alternatively (in this case, `Array.prototype.reduce` is perfect)

Comment: @JamesMonger or you can write a new answer that doesn't yous jQuery so people can see alternative answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a JSON object, [**there's no such a thing as a "JSON Object"**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), it's nothing but a Javascript `object`.

But to answer your question, ***I want to get the total marks per student.***:

You can simply do it using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)**, **[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)** and **[`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b)** methods.

This is how should be your code:

```
var results = Object.keys(data.students).map(function(key) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[key] = Object.values(data.students[key]).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return obj;
});
```

**Explanation:**

The following code works like this:

- We use `Object.keys(data.students)` to get all the keys (students names) from the `students`object.
- Then we loop over these keys with `.map()` method to return a custom object for each iterated key.
- Then inside the `.map()` loop, for each key we get all the values of the `object` relative to this key (the marks values) with `Object.values(data.students[key])`.
- And finally we use `.reduce()` method with the marks array taken from `Object.values()` call, and return a sum of these values.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {
  "students": {
    "ABC": {
      "eng": 25,
      "maths": 50,
      "sci": 25
    },
    "DEF": {
      "eng": 25,
      "maths": 48,
      "sci": 30
    }
  }
};

var results = Object.keys(data.students).map(function(key) {
  let obj = {};
  obj[key] = Object.values(data.students[key]).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you chose to output the results like this. Why did you choose to have an array of objects with only a single key/value pair in each?

Comment: @JamesMonger The OP clearly said ***I want to get the total marks per student.***, so the result I provided meets exactly this requirement and returns a total per student.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer doesn't meet the requirements. I'm asking why you formatted like that rather than like: `{ "ABC": 1, "DEF": 2 }`